# Product rule for quaternions

Tags: derivatives, lie-groups, quaternions

The following exercise is from *Naive Lie Theory* by Stillwell, and is designed (I assume) to illustrate how non-commutativity of quaternions affects the product rule.

The definition of derivative for any function $c(t)$ of a real variable $t$ is 
$$c'(t) = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{c(t + \Delta t) - c(t)}{\Delta t}.$$

(1) By imitating the usual proof of the product rule, show that if $c(t) = a(t)b(t)$ then $$c'(t) = a'(t)b(t) + a(t)b'(t).$$
(Do not assume the product rule is  commutative.)

(2) Show also that if $c(t) = a(t)^{-1}$, and $a(0) = 1$, then $c'(0)= -a'(0),$ again without assuming that the product is commutative.

(3) Show, however, that if $c(t)=a(t)^2$ then $c'(t)$ is *not* equal to $2a(t)a'(t)$ for a certain quaternionic-valued function $a(t)$.

Parts (1) and (2) are straightforward, but I just cannot get the certain quaternionic-valued function for part (3). Does anyone know what it is? For the function $a(t)$ I've tried: $it, jt, (i+j)t, ijt, e^jt$ and a whole bunch of others without success. If anyone knows it, i'd be grateful, thanks.

Comment: Since $\frac{d}{dt}a(t)^2=a'(t)a(t)+a(t)a'(t)$, in order for this to not equal $2a(t)a'(t)$ we must have $a'(t)a(t)\ne a(t)a'(t)$, that is $a(t)$ and $a'(t)$ can't commute. Since $a(t)=\int_0^t a'(u)du+a(0)$ is heuristically like a sum of $a'(u)$ values, we should try to make $a'(u_1)$ not commute with $a'(u_2)$ for most pairs $u_1,u_2$. Two quaternions commute iff they lie in the same copy of the complex plane, so if we parametrize an affine line that spans more than one imaginary direction we should be good. This is what José's answer does.

Comment: Right, got it. Thank you for the added context, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a(t)=it+j$, then $c(t)=a^2(t)=-1-t^2$, and therefore$$2a(t)a'(t)=2(it+j)i=-2t-k,$$which is *not* $c'(t)$.